# Prove vertical angles are congruent.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Prove vertical angles are congruent.

I don't yet know degrees. 
All I know is congruent angles have congruent supplements. 
Is it too easy to just say that if I have two intersecting lines AC and BD and their intersecting point is X. < CXD is supplementary to < CXB by theorem. And < CXB is supplementary to < BXA. Thus < CXD must be congruent to < BXA because they share the same supplement? I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Yup, its all :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's all there is to it.